# How to get Host OS (operating system) parameter of ZIP archive in C#

Tags: c#, zip, operating-system, host

Look. I have ZIP archives prepared in different os'es: mac, linux, windows.
In windows file names encoded in DOS CP866, mac & linux in UTF-8. I need to know (in code) in which os zip file was prepared to decode file names correctly.
There is a Host OS paramterer in "Central directory structure" of zip file (look http://www.fileformat.info/format/zip/corion.htm ).
How to get 0005h  1 byte   Host OS parameter in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a `StreamReader` to get this particular position in the file? I believe you can tell it what offset and length you'd like to read, and it will fetch that set of bytes of you, which will tell you the OS.